# Opening windows in tabs (nesting)

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm working on nesting a series of pages that break off of a certain window you are currently tabbed to. When you click a button, it should jump you to the next page, but it only does if I use `win.containingTab.open()` to call the next page. After that, I can use `win.open()` to navigate to my next windows, but I lose my toolbar functionality as well as my window bar functionality. I'm working on doing this for iOS at the moment. Suggestions?

Comment: Post some more code, right now your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to (and only way) to do this is to contain every single page inside a tab group and then just navigate to it using `win.open()`.